# How do i make copy constructor for 2 pointer variable in c++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, copy-constructor, definition

I have two pointer variables as data members. How do I make copies of these two data members? How do I make a deep copy constructor for this? I tried many times, but it's not working.

```cpp
class abc {
    float *number1;
    float *number2;

public:
    abc(float l,float w)
    {
       number1 = new float;
       number2 = new float;
       number1 = &l;
       number2 = &w;
    }
    
    float get_1()
    {
        return *number1;
    }
    
    float get_2()
    {
        return *number2;    
    }
    
    abc(const abc& ob)
    {
        number1 = ob.number1;
        number2 = ob.number2;
    }
    
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Number 1 : " << *number1 << endl;
        cout << "Number 2 : " << *number2 << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: John, let's start with code alignment first. Then read this: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/shallow-vs-deep-copying/

Comment: Why dynamically allocate two `float`s instead of: `float number1; float number2;` and not have to bother?

Comment: @TedLyngmo ... and overwrite the pointers by meanlgless local pointers, causing memory leak?

Comment: If you change the `float*`'s into just regular `float`'s, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Maybe one day it will be array of floats, so he wants to learn...Slow down people..

Comment: @MikeCAT Pretty sure they mean change the class members to `float` from `float*`

Comment: But I make deep constructor and i have no idea how to deal with

Comment: If change float pointer to float variable i can easily make shallow copy but my task to deep copy

Comment: @john Again: Why are you using `new` there then at all, if you don't want to share pointers?!? _"If change float pointer to float variable i can easily make shallow copy but my task to deep copy"_ Huh, what please?

Comment: I am using new for allocating new memory when i make new object

Comment: @john But you definitely don't need `new` there.

Comment: @john Have you been programming in another language where using `new` is the proper way to do this?

Comment: "I try many times but its not working" <- not a problem description. Explain what you have tried, what output you want, what output you get instead, and how that is wrong.

Comment: "but my task to deep copy" Is your instructor deliberately teaching you bad C++, or do they just not know better?

Comment: I want that 2 data member copy into another object when i call copy constructor

Comment: but condition is these 2 data member will be pointer

Comment: Of course one shouldn't store floats as pointers in a case like this, but one also wouldn't name their class "abc" and members "number1" and "number2". Man's just giving a simple example to learn a new concept, people should chill about it.

Comment: @tilz0R one day they will learn about `std::vector`, there is no reason to use pointers here

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 do you think vector is faster than new on microcontroller? What is value is big? Who handles realloc for vector.

Answer (score 2):

Also your constructor is wrong:

```
abc(float l,float w)
{
   number1= new float;
   number2=new float;
   number1 =&l; //this will overwrite the pointer returned by new with the address of a local variable
   number2=&w; //the same
}
```

you should do this:

```
abc(float l,float w)
{
   number1= new float(l); // allocate a float and set the value to l
   number2=new float(w); // allocate a float and set the value to w
}
```

And the copy constructor is quite similar:

```
abc(const abc& ob)
{
    number1 = new float(*ob.number1); // allocate a float and set the value to number1 from the other object
    number2 = new float(*ob.number2); // allocate a float and set the value to number2 from the other object
}
```

This example can be improved further by using the initializer list of the constructors:

```
abc(float l,float w) :
        number1 { new float(l)},
        number2 { new float(w)}
{
}

abc(const abc& ob) :
        number1 { new float(*ob.number1)},
        number2 { new float(*ob.number2)}
{
}
```

Comment: You mean `new float(*ob.number1)` instead of `new float(ob.number1)`? (also for `number2`)

Comment: @john If you are going to give feedback on answers, you'd better be more precise. "not working" doesn't provide any insight into what it is that's not working.

Answer (score 2):

For starters this constructor

```
abc(float l,float w)
{
   number1 = new float;
   number2 = new float;
   number1 = &l;
   number2 = &w;
}
```

produces memory leaks. At first a memory was allocated in these statements

```
   number1 = new float;
   number2 = new float;
```

and its addresses were assigned to pointers. But then at once the pointers were reassigned

```
   number1 = &l;
   number2 = &w;
```

So the addresses to the allocated memory were lost.

The constructor can look at least the following way

```
abc( float l, float w ) : number1( new float( l ) ), number2( new float( w ) )
{
}
```

These functions

```
float get_1()
{
    return *number1;
}

float get_2()
{
    return *number2;    
}
```

should be declared like

```
float get_1() const
{
    return *number1;
}

float get_2() const
{
    return *number2;    
}
```

In general it is better to define these functions like

```
const float & get_1() const
{
    return *number1;
}

const float & get_2() const
{
    return *number2;    
}

float & get_1()
{
    return *number1;
}

float & get_2()
{
    return *number2;    
}
```

The copy constructor can look like

```
abc( const abc &ob) 
    : number1( new float( *ob.number1 ) ), number2( new float( *ob.number2 ) )
{
}
```

The function display should look at least like

```
void display() const 
{
    cout << "Number 1 : " << *number1 << endl;
    cout << "Number 2 : " << *number2 << endl;
}
```

Instead of this function you could define a friend operator <<. For example

```
class abc
{
    //...
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const abc &ob )
    {
        os << "Number 1 : " << *ob.number1 << std::endl;
        os << "Number 2 : " << *ob.number2 << std::endl;

        return os;
    }
}
```

Also you should define explicitly the copy assignment operator and the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
void display()
{
    cout<<"Number 1 : "<<number1<<endl;
    cout<<"Number 2 :"<<number2<endl;
}
```

This will print the location in memory of the numbers.  Is that what you want?  To display the value of the numbers

```
void display()
{
    cout<<"Number 1 : "<< *number1 << endl;
    cout<<"Number 2 : "<< *number2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is not really an answer. He wants to do copy of the data in the right way, so new alloc and copy then.

Comment: I didn't give you negative feedback, but I want to point that asking him what he wants is not SO answer :) I rather give positive feedback when possible, and nothing when not.